# Laravel 5.3 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php when try to post

Tags: php, laravel

In my routes/web.php file

```
Route::get('/users', [
    'uses' => 'Admin\UsersController@Index',
    'as' => 'users'
]);
Route::post('/adduser', [
    'uses' => 'Admin\UsersController@Create',
    'as' => 'adduser'
]);
```

This is my index.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('adduser')}}" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">User Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control input-circle" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adını Yazınız">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

When i try to post this or another submit form, I got an error which says "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218". I would appreciate any help to solve this error. Hope you guys help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change route to `patch` to make it work:

```
Route::patch('/adduser', [
    'uses' => 'Admin\UsersController@Create',
    'as' => 'adduser'
]);
```

Or change `_method` to `POST`:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="POST">
```

Answer (score 1):

You passed the `PATCH` Method From your Form. But in your route file you defined `POST` route instead of `PATCH`

```
Route::post('/adduser', [
    'uses' => 'Admin\UsersController@Create',
    'as' => 'adduser'
]);
```

Remove this line from your form:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

Otherwise you can change the value `PATCH` to `POST`

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change value of "_method" to POST. Since your route and your form method are all POST.

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="POST">
```